# How to get count of post of each user by day on mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to get count of post of each user by day on mongodb? I have a similar dataset like below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58863104f9881947d6d328c3"), 
  "time" : 1484755908748,
  "user" : "mjt",
  "post" : "lorem ipsum...."
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58863104f9881947d6d328c3"), 
  "time" : 1484755908748,
  "user" : "joe",
  "post" : "lorem ipsum...."
}
....
```

simple try I did but gave error

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
  { $project: {user:1, 
    isoTime : {$dayOfMonth : {$add : [new Date(0),"$time"]}} }}, 
    {$group : {_id:"$isoTime", count: {$sum:1}}} 
])
```

this gives error :

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type null to Date",
"code" : 16006,
"codeName" : "Location16006"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to filter your collection for documents which have the `time` field (i.e. it is not null) and where the type is `NOT` a date and then group per user per day using the **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString)** operator which produces a formatted date time string that will represent the day.

Run the following aggregate operation to get the count of posts per day

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { "time": { "$exists": true, "$not": { "$type": 9 } } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                    "date": { "$add": [new Date(0), "$time"] }
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
        }
    } 
])
```

And this pipeline should give you both the number of posts per user per day and the overall post count for that day:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { "time": { "$exists": true, "$not": { "$type": 9 } } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "user": "$user",
                "yearMonthDay": {   
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        "date": { "$add": [new Date(0), "$time"] }
                    }
                }
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.yearMonthDay",
            "userCounts": {
                "$push": {
                    "user": "$_id.user",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            },
            "total": { "$sum": "$count" }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some documents in your collection have `time` equal to `null`. When you are converting null to Date, you get this error. Simply filter out such documents with $match stage (add it before other stages):

```
{ $match: { time: {$type: 9}}}
```

9 is a value for [BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) Date.